# Pop up calendar for date selection in selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

how to select date from calendar pop up? There's a text field which is in disabled mode. When you click on the calendar icon at the corner of the text field the calendar pops up which displays the current date. I need to select the date which is two years back. How do i go about doing that in selenium java?

below is the html code:

```html
<div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu" style="display: block; top: 429.1px; left: 234.5px;">
<div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block;">
 <table class=" table-condensed">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;">
    <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>
    </th>
    <th class="switch" colspan="5">February 2009</th>
    <th class="next" style="visibility: visible;">
    <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th class="dow">Su</th>
    <th class="dow">Mo</th>
    <th class="dow">Tu</th>
    <th class="dow">We</th>
    <th class="dow">Th</th>
    <th class="dow">Fr</th>
    <th class="dow">Sa</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
   <tr>
   <tr>
   <tr>
   <tr>
   <tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none;">
 <table class="table-condensed">
  <thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="7">
     <span class="month">Jan</span>
     <span class="month">Feb</span>
     <span class="month">Mar</span>
     <span class="month">Apr</span>
     <span class="month">May</span>
     <span class="month">Jun</span>
     <span class="month">Jul</span>
     <span class="month">Aug</span>
     <span class="month">Sep</span>
     <span class="month">Oct</span>
     <span class="month">Nov</span>
     <span class="month">Dec</span>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="datepicker-years" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you having difficulty working out how to do the UI actions, or is the difficult bit figuring out how to enter a particular date from two years in the past?

Answer (score 0):

use try catch statement

In try u can search for the element to be present in the page (any unique element related to the date to be selected)

In catch block you can click on the back button .
so in this case it will keep clicking on back/previous button in the calender to go to the previuos year .